# Why is a printer not deployed to a specific station?

Tags: group-policy, network-printer, deployment

I have my printers deployed through GP with success for every machine on the network.

One specific machine - is the exception. It's a MAC Air with W7 installed.

It's gperesult is pasted:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001

Created On 9/21/2011 at 9:19:37 AM



RSOP data for company\ranm on LTAIRRAN : Logging Mode
------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   Default-First-Site-Name
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\ranm.company.000
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=LTAIRRAN,OU=Laptops,OU=Default,OU=company Computers,DC=company
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 9/21/2011 at 8:30:19 AM
    Group Policy was applied from:      companyDC.company
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        company
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy
        Firewall - Remote Administration 
        Remove UAC
        SOPHOS Tasks Enabler
        WSUS Settings - All

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        LTAIRRAN$
        Domain Computers
        System Mandatory Level


USER SETTINGS
--------------
    CN=Ran Machtinger,OU=Mng_Department,OU=company_Users,DC=company
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 9/21/2011 at 8:30:19 AM
    Group Policy was applied from:      companyDC.company
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        company
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy
        Default Group Policy Object

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Firewall - Remote Administration 
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The user is a part of the following security groups
    ---------------------------------------------------
        Domain Users
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        CONSOLE LOGON
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        LOCAL
        APP_DEP_RW
        SALES_DEP_RW
        PR_DEP_RW
        RD_DEP_RW
        QA_DEP_RW
        MNG_DEP_RW
        High Mandatory Level
```

As you can see, pushprinterconnections is in the logon script.

I tried login with a different user on the same PC, same result - no printer.

The GP is the: Domain Default Policy.
It's security settings are for: Authenticated Users
[image]

- even that the -log settings is set on the script, I can't find any log PPCuser/PPCMachine in it's corresponding directory.
  [image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First place of research when something breaks with group policy or similar: Event Log on the local client.

Things that usually break printers via GPO and/or logon scripts:

- Untrusted driver (as in not WHQL-certified). You have to manually deploy the driver(s) as administrator before pushing out printers.
- Conflicting device. Are you sure that there are no local printers installed with the same name?

Things that usually break everything that has to do with logon scripts:

- Incorrect time on the local client. Make sure it's in sync with the domain (net time /set). Also make sure that it's in the correct timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps either the script or the exe isn't visible to the computer executing the policy, for whatever reason. The GPO seems fine. Checked the event log for Policy errors or tried a traced log on?